# Views from Multiple Subqueries MYSQL

Tags: mysql, math, subquery

I have a mathematical code that requires two subqueries. Below is the copy of the code.

```
SELECT AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp, ProduceMonAvg.Avergae_CPI,
SUM(AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp) as AVGTEMPSUM,
SUM(ProduceMonAvg.Average_CPI) as PROCPISUM,
SUM(AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp*AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp) AS AVGTEMPSQ,
SUM(ProduceMonAvg.Average_CPI*ProduceMonAvg.Average_CPI)PROCPISQ,
SUM(AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp*ProduceMonAvg.Average_CPI) AS PowerSum,
COUNT(*) as COUNT,
(COUNT*(PowerSum)-(AVGTEMPSUM))/(sqrt(COUNT*(AVGTEMPSQ)-pow(AVGTEMPSUM,2)*
    (COUNT*(PROCPISQ)-pow(PROCPISUM,2)))) AS Correlation
FROM(SELECT series_id,FORMAT(AVG(value),2) AS Average_CPI, period
FROM CURRENT
WHERE series_id = 'CUSR0000SEFK'
AND theYear >=(1997)
AND theYear <=(2010)
GROUP BY period) AS ProduceMonAvg,
(SELECT Average_Temp
FROM AVGTEMP_X)
INNER JOIN ProduceMonAvg
ON AVGTEMP_X.period = ProduceMonAvg.period
```

I get an error saying

> 1146 - Table 'xxx.ProduceMonAvg' doesn't exist
>
> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'COUNT' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your outer query, you reference `ProdcueMonAvg.Average_CPI` etc. In your inner query, you alias it as `AS ProduceMonAvg`. note the typo - `Prodcue` vs `Produce`. Are you sure your error doesn't say `Table xxx.ProdcueMonAvg doesn't exist`?

For that matter, there are a couple of other things that seem wrong with your query. Your join to the AVGTEMP_X query is using a subquery where one isn't necessary, it's also performing a cross join and THEN an inner join. I doubt that is what you wanted. Try this one out:

```
    SELECT AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp,
    ProduceMonAvg.Average_CPI,
    SUM(AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp) AS AVGTEMPSUM,
    SUM(ProduceMonAvg.Average_CPI) AS PROCPISUM,
     SUM(AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp * AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp) AS AVGTEMPSQ,
    SUM(ProduceMonAvg.Average_CPI * ProduceMonAvg.Average_CPI) PROCPISQ,
    SUM(AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp * ProduceMonAvg.Average_CPI) AS PowerSum,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
     (COUNT(*) * (SUM(AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp * ProduceMonAvg.Average_CPI)) - (SUM(AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp))) / (sqrt(COUNT(*)* (SUM(AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp * AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp)) - pow(SUM(AVGTEMP_X.Average_Temp), 2) * (COUNT(*)* (SUM(ProduceMonAvg.Average_CPI * ProduceMonAvg.Average_CPI)) - pow(SUM(ProduceMonAvg.Average_CPI), 2)))) AS Correlation
FROM (
    SELECT series_id,
        FORMAT(AVG(value), 2) AS Average_CPI,
        period
    FROM CURRENT
    WHERE series_id = 'CUSR0000SEFK'
        AND theYear >= (1997)
        AND theYear <= (2010)
    GROUP BY period
    ) AS ProduceMonAvg
INNER JOIN AVGTEMP_X ON AVGTEMP_X.period = ProduceMonAvg.period
```

I've also created some mock tables and data and finally tested the query. It returns results. You can see it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47523/14

Comment: @AndrewHernandez Even after fixing it, it still contains typos. `ON AVGTEMP_X.period = ProdcueMonAvg.period` for your join predicate

Comment: Yea, it has been a long work week for me and typos are killing me. ALL HAVE BEEN FIXED AS OF NOW

Comment: Ah. don't use `COUNT` as the alias, always best to avoid using mysql reserved words. make it 'total' or some such instead. I'll amend my query for you. also, there were some other typos on `avergae` vs `average`.

Comment: sorry - having a tired moment as well. You can't refer to column aliases anywhere other than the `GROUP BY` `HAVING` or `ORDER BY` clauses. This means you have to use `COUNT(*)` instead of the alias in the additional calculations. i've modified again, sorry :(

Comment: I just hard coded the count for now and now I am getting

>1054 - Unknown column 'PowerSum' in 'field list'

Comment: It's the same thing as I mentioned above. You can't alias the calculation result, and then use that alias in further calculations in the same select clause. You will need to substitute the actual calculation in each place you use the alias. Messy yes, but necessary. I've again updated the query to remove those. (Sorry - hard to test the query without some data / tables :))

Comment: @AndrewHernandez i've fixed all of the typos and alias references, and tested the query on some sample data [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47523/14). so it should be working now :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I had the equation wrong, I fixed the equation and you code helped.